# Why reading from a view is way slower than reading from a table?

Tags: mysql, performance, denormalization

I was doing some **tests** under MySQL about denormalization. I had three tables *t1, t2, t3*

t1 = {**c1**,c2,h1}
t2 = {*c1*, *c3*}
t3 = {**c3**, c4, c5, c6}
**Pirmary Key** *Foreign Key*

t1 has 2000 tuples, t2 the same and t3 1000 tuples.

I created a program to simulate 500 concurrent users doing one query each one. These are the results I've got.

```
SELECT t3.c5 FROM t3
 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.c3 = t3.c3
 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
WHERE t3.c4 > 100
```

**This takes 2326 ms**

Then I created a view using the previous query `CREATE VIEW vista AS SELECT *...` and I launched again 500 users but now with this query:

```
SELECT c5 FROM vista WHERE c4 > 100
```

And **it took 2405 ms! (more than using JOIN)**

And then I tried the following query:

```
SELECT c5 FROM t3 WHERE c4 > 100
```

**It took 827 ms**

---

So, what makes a SELECT performed on a view take so long to complete? Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: `c4` isn't indexed... and did you take OS / DB caching into account?

Comment: @Ben ok, c4 is not indexed, but is not in the last query either, and it only took 827ms. What you mean by OS/DB caching?

Comment: I mean that if you're running queries that select the same data then the chances are that the OS or the DB is caching something, which could easily explain how quickly this is running. Run it a few more times and you should see the time getting quicker and quicker.

Comment: @Ben but i guess that caching will affect each query, not just the last one...